# PHP generate HTML convert to JPG then to PDF

Tags: php, html, pdf

I'm developing an app where the user adds items to a list. That list is stored in an array and passed to PHP with JSON. 
The objective is to then create a PDF with all the values extracted from the user. The PDF is quite complicated. It includes images depending on what the user selects and the text varies depending on the images and the input data.
The first idea was to generate the pdf in php with one of those pdf libraries, but that's going to be a real hassle.
Then I thought of creating an html & css (much easier) and the convert it to PDF. But since the html & css are quite complex I don't think those pdf converters will work with this.
Then I thought I could convert the html to jpg and then to pdf.

It'll be much simpler if I could just use html but the output needs to be pdf.

What do you suggest?

Comment: How complex is the HTML+CSS? Some of the rendering libraries are quite capable. The more powerful rendering engines typically require binary installation (see wkhtmltopdf), but even some of the PHP-only solutions are pretty good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a post that discusses creating PDF files with PHP and the PDFLib extension.

[Generate PDFs with PHP](http://blogs.sitepoint.com/generate-pdfs-php/) it's on sitepoint.

Or if you want to go from HTML to the PDF it looks like [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/) might work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/)

Comment: That was the first thing I thought but the pdf's are way to complicated create them like that. My idea was to have an editable pdf and change the text with php but FPDF allows to create pdf not to edit them.

Answer (score 0):

> Then I thought of creating an html & css (much easier) and the convert it to PDF. But since the html & css are quite complex I don't think those pdf converters will work with this.

[wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) to the rescue!  If you are on a VPS or dedicated machine, it's probably the best (open source) HTML-to-PDF engine out there.  It leverages Webkit, the rendering engine used by Google Chrome and Apple Safari, amongst others.

Otherwise, your only other options are going to involve *drawing every aspect of the PDF or image yourself, "by hand"* in your code.